# Not able to use ajaxSubmit : TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxSubmit'

Tags: jquery, ajax

You'll have to bear with me, as I am just starting out with jQuery so this may be a very simple thing I am overlooking.
I have a login form for a site that I am developing, and I am trying to use ajaxSubmit to send the request for a lost password request. This request originates from a form on a modal div.

Form:

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none" title="Retrieve your password">
        <p>
            Please enter your username below and you will have a new password sent to the email address you registered with the account.
        </p>
        <form id="passform" action="comment.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
        </form>
    </div>
```

jQuery to submit request:

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            function doit(formData, jqForm, options)
            {
                // formData is an array; here we use $.param to convert it to a string to display it
                // but the form plugin does this for you automatically when it submits the data
                var queryString = $.param(formData);

                // jqForm is a jQuery object encapsulating the form element.  To access the
                // DOM element for the form do this:
                // var formElement = jqForm[0];

                alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString);

                // here we could return false to prevent the form from being submitted;
                // returning anything other than false will allow the form submit to continue
                return true;
            }


            $("#getpass").click(function()
            {

                $("#dialog").dialog(
                {
                    autoOpen : true,
                    resizable : false,
                    height : 270,
                    modal : true,
                    hide : "fold",
                    show : "fold",
                    buttons :
                    {
                        "Retrieve Password" : function()
                        {
                            $("#passform").ajaxSubmit(
                            {
                                url : "php/lostpassword.php",
                                type : "post",
                                success : doit
                            });
                            return false;
                        },
                        Cancel : function()
                        {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }

                    }
                });

            });

        });
```

However, when I actually hit the button, I get the following console error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxSubmit'

I have checked that the ID's all match up and that the relevant js files are being loaded.

I'm running out of ideas now, can anyone help?

Comment: are you using a plugin to be using ajaxSubmit?

Comment: Are you using a plugin? because ajaxSubmit is a part of Jquery Form Plugin, if that is the case, check it if plugin is included correctly

Comment: Yup, I have this in the head:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

Comment: do you have `//` before the urls in your script tags?

Comment: Yes, the SO interface must have trimmed them.
I do have the full URL in the script tags eg.
http: //malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js

Comment: what browser are you using?  Do you have developer tools to monitor the Network?  Are the js files getting loaded successfully?

Comment: strange i bet something small, can you post your full html too? maybe we will spot something fishy :)

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97
The full html for the page Ive pasted to 
http://pastebin.com/8jdeixDB 
Also thank you so much for your help guys!

Comment: Really weird, everything works fine here. http://jsfiddle.net/DumnF/..  Make sure that the plugin is getting loaded successfully in the network tab of developer tools

Comment: Absolutely bizarre... Checking the network tab it was getting loaded absolutely fine. Just to be sure, I downloaded the hard code and loaded it from my JS directory, loaded fine and Im still getting the 'has no method' error.

Comment: I dont know if itll help, but the actual site is at http://test.automike.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference, the error was being thrown because I'm an idiot :/
I'd apparently included two different versions of jQuery, as soon as I removed the extra include it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error message, and resolved by adding jQuery Form plugin, which has ajaxSubmit function.